# Clean memory on multiple returns - Function C++

Tags: c++, return, code-cleanup

I am using a function with multiple return paths. But on every one of them I need to clean the memory,release some objects,etc. I have seen on the internet some methods but I don't think they are "standard" or even fail-proof (`goto` statements). I believe this is a common situation and it may prove useful for others with same the same problem.

Here's an example:

```
//Opening many handles//
//.....

//The actual code
void *imgBytes;
bmp = CreateDIBSection(memHDC, &bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &imgBytes, NULL, NULL);
HGDIOBJ oldSelect = SelectObject(memHDC, bmp);


BitBlt(memHDC, 0, 0, screenW, rowHeight, screen, 0, yOffset, SRCCOPY);
GdiFlush();

//Memory leaks
if(!condition1) return false;
if(!condition2) return false;
if(!condition3) return false;
if(!condition4) return false;
if(!condition5) return false;
if(!condition6) return false;


//Code to be executed on every return
SelectObject(memHDC, oldSelect);
DeleteDC(memHDC);
DeleteObject(bmp);
ReleaseDC(NULL, screen);
```

One solution to this problem could be just to insert every `if` inside another(but I doesn't solve the problem):

```
if(condition1){
    if(condition1){
        if(condition1){
            if(condition1){
                //continue execution...
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}


//One of the conditions above failed. Clean code
SelectObject(memHDC, oldSelect);
DeleteDC(memHDC);
DeleteObject(bmp);
ReleaseDC(NULL, screen);

return false;
```

How can I solve this problem but without `goto's` .

Comment: [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization)

Comment: This scenario is one of the main reasons modern exception handling has become popular. Your main choices are gotos, or copy the cleanup code - or RAII, as @Nathan suggests (which is really implicit exception handling).

Comment: Use [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization)! It's one of the best things about C++ and you would benefit greatly from it. You can wrap your resources in classes or helpers like `unique_ptr`s that do the cleanup work automatically and seamlessly. In a sense, you can forget about cleanup entirely using RAII.

Comment: You can use `std::unique_ptr` with custom deleter

Comment: Nice ideea. What if I "send" all the data to the instance of a class and implement all the cleaning in the destructor(this is almost what unique_ptr does)? A long way...but better than goto. I will also check RAII

Comment: "I will also check RAII" using `std::unique_ptr` or custom class is actually RAII, just using `std::unique_ptr` is simpler and cleaner as it requires less code written and that class disabled possible ways of leaking the resource it manages